# Show Edit button when radio button is checked

Tags: jquery, html

I have to Input radio buttons namely

```
Radio1

Radio2
```

With 2 hidden edit anchor links, I have written JQuery code for showing and hiding Edit links when clicked on radio buttons its works superbly but when i refresh my page by default radio1 is checked during first time it will not show edit link when i click for second time it shows edit link.

By default if radio button is checked show edit link can somebody help me out in achieving it Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/qx69o1bd/6/

**Html**

```
<div>
    <input id="radio-1" class="radio-custom rad_1" name="top_Ad" type="radio" checked>
    <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label" style='font-size:14px;'>Radio1</label>
    <a style='display:none' href="#" class="edit1">Edit</a>
</div>

<div>
    <input id="radio-2" class="radio-custom rad_2" name="top_Ad" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-2" class="radio-custom-label" style='font-size:14px;'>Radio2</label>
    <a style='display:none' href="#" class="edit2">Edit</a>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".rad_1").click(function () {
    $(".edit1").show();
    $(".edit2").hide();
});

$(".rad_2").click(function () {
    $(".edit2").show();
    $(".edit1").hide();
});
```

Comment: Just remove `style='display:none'` from the first checkbox(_or the default checked checkbox_). Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/qx69o1bd/10/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".rad_1").click();
```

manually call the click event to show the edit link

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/qx69o1bd/7/)

```
$(".rad_1").click(function () {
    $(".edit1").show();
    $(".edit2").hide();
});
$(".rad_1").click();
$(".rad_2").click(function () {
    $(".edit2").show();
    $(".edit1").hide();
});
```

Since you are using radio button I suggest that you change you event from click to change. Click event is used for button and change event is used for radio button checkbox and select

```
$(".rad_1").change(function () {
    $(".edit1").show();
    $(".edit2").hide();
});
$(".rad_1").change();
$(".rad_2").change(function () {
    $(".edit2").show();
    $(".edit1").hide();
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/qx69o1bd/13/)

Comment: Suggest `change` event instead of `click`, and use `trigger('change');`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qx69o1bd/11/

Thank You Pekka .. one small change if i change checked to radio2 i should get edit link in radio2 but it showing in radio1.. can u help me out if checked i should see edit instead of click Thanks

Comment: @Sjay CHECK my comment on the question, I think that's better way. :)

Comment: @Pekka If you want to use same thing, use `$(':radio:checked').siblings('a').show();` in `ready`. Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/qx69o1bd/14/)

Comment: @Tushar Thank You for your suggestion n valuable time..i just wanted to show and hide edit link based on checked attribute Thanks

Comment: @Sjay Welcome. Glad to help :)

Comment: @Sjay did you check the demo?it is working just as you wanted it

Answer (score 1):

I have changed class name of the links which can help to write some consize code.

1. changed the class name of links to a common `.edit` instead of `.edit1, .edit2`.
2. Use `change` event instead of click and make sure to trigger it on page load to show the edit link which is in the block of the checked radio.

You can change a little to get the desired effect:

```js
$('.radio-custom').change(function() {
  $('.edit').hide(); // 2. hide all the .edit links
  $(".radio-custom:checked").siblings('.edit').show(); // 3. only show the edit link which is the sibling of the checked radio
}).change(); // <----1. trigger the change to show the hidden edit link;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="radio-1" class="radio-custom rad_1" name="top_Ad" type="radio" checked>
  <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label" style='font-size:14px;'>Radio1</label>
  <a style='display:none' href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
</div>

<div>
  <input id="radio-2" class="radio-custom rad_2" name="top_Ad" type="radio">
  <label for="radio-2" class="radio-custom-label" style='font-size:14px;'>Radio2</label>
  <a style='display:none' href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `$(".radio-custom:checked")` => `$(this)`, as the clicked radio will be **always** the checked one.

Comment: @Tushar accepted. but won't work in this case becasue when i do then second of the edit is shown. especially when OP want to show at dom ready.

Comment: @Tushar _as the clicked radio will be **always** the checked one_ not in this case.

Comment: Yes, because you're triggering event. `$(':radio:checked').siblings('a').show();` was in my mind, use this in ready instead of trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger click on first start :

```
$(".rad_1").click(function(){
   $(".edit1").show();
   $(".edit2").hide();
}).click(); //<---- here
```